# angular-route jquery dependency

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-routing, angularjs-ng-route

The index.html (layout page):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="web">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- v2.1.1 -->
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script> <!-- v1.2.24 -->
    <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script> <!-- v1.2.24 -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var web = angular.module("web", ['ngRoute']);
    web.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'page1.html'
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body data-ng-view>
</body>
</html>
```

The page1.html (child page):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myController($scope) {
    $scope.foo='foo';
}
</script>

<div data-ng-controller="myController">
    {{foo}}
</div>
```

If you remove jQuery from main page (index.html), angular-route is not able to find the controller (myController). Can anyone tell me if this is a bug or I am doing something wrong?

I am using angular.min.js v1.2.24, angular-route.min.js v1.2.24 and jquery.min.js v2.1.1.

Comment: The problem remains same with angular v1.2.25.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try if this work? (not tested)

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="web">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script> <!-- v1.2.24 -->
    <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script> <!-- v1.2.24 -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var web = angular.module("web", ['ngRoute']);
    web.controller('myController', function($scope) {
        $scope.foo='foo';
    });
    web.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'page1.html',
            controller: 'myController'
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body data-ng-view>
</body>
</html>
```

page1.html

```
<div>
    {{foo}}
</div>
```

ref: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

Comment: Your solution definitely works, but I don't want loading of all the scripts (controllers, services etc.) at start up. The idea is to load the scripts on demand and as late as possible.

Comment: Why? The runtime doesn't matter, I think.